# I have 2 Pythons on my Mac, how do I use a specific version of Python in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, version, updates

I use Anaconda and Pycharm. For some reason, anaconda uses Python 3.9, but Pycharm uses Python 3.11. When I install modules, they are installed on Python 3.9. I need to use those modules in Pycharm (Python 3.11). How do I do this?

Have no idea what I should do. I heard that Homebrew can do this, but I have zero idea of what Homebrew is and how it can help me.

Comment: I would encourage you to learn a bit more about conda environments.

Conda is the command that allows you to create environments (conda is part of Anaconda). The idea is that you create development environments inside your machine and you can create different environments for different purposes. These environments are isolated from everything else which is super convenient. Then you should be able to use your environments on your IDE (Pycharm or Visual Studio Code).

Maybe look for some videos on YouTube about the topic, you will not regret learning about this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the top right corner of Pycharm, you'll find the configurations. Click "Edit Configurations"

Next, under "Environment" change the "Python Interpreter" to the version you are using. If there isn't a python interpreter for the version you want to use, go into settings (CTR + ALT + S). Then click on "Project", then "Python Interpreter".

[image]
On this page, you can click the cog (which is settings), and you can add interpreters from your system.

Comment: I don't use Pycharm, but a quick search pointed me to this which seems useful: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#packages .